# Cannot create new rails 3.2.6 site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed ruby 1.9.3p194.  I have also installed rails 3.2.8,3.2.6,and 3.0.3.  I am able to create a new site using rails versions 3.2.8 and 3.0.3.  When I try to create a site with rails 3.2.6 it rails to work.

`rails _3.2.6_ new example`

```
/Users/Dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:317:in `bin_path': can't find gem rails (["3.2.6"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Users/Dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/Dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I have tried uninstalling 3.2.6 and reinstalling but the result is the same.  Any help would on this would be great.

UPDATE: I was able to solve this problem by uninstalling both 3.2.6 and 3.0.3 and then reinstalling 3.2.6.  Not sure why this worked but it does. At some point I need to install 3.0.3 can these versions not co-exist?

Comment: Best way to do this is to use gemsets. `rvm use 1.9.3-p194@rails326 --create` to create a gemset and use that one to manage your Rails versions. https://rvm.io/gemsets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time looking at gemsets that was definitely the solution to this problem.  I set up [RVM](http://rvm.io) and installed two versions of Ruby. Then I setup [gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/) for each version that had the version of rails I needed to write code for the book I was working through and the web server I am using.